# Select rows after a specific ID

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have the following query, it chooses from a news articles table. Due to multiple sorting factors, I cannot locate the next page of date.

The parameter I have is the last ID in the query result set, so how can I fetch the next page... **Again, I don't have a page index, all I have is the last ID from the previous query result set**

```
SELECT TOP (20) ID, 
                Datediff(SECOND, CONVERT(DATETIME, '1970-01-01', 102), 
                RELEASE_DATE) AS date, 
                Datediff(SECOND, CONVERT(DATETIME, '1970-01-01', 102), EDIT_DATE 
                )    AS lastchanged, 
                IMPORTANT 
FROM   ARTICLES AS news WITH (NOLOCK) 
WHERE  ( STATUS = 1 ) 
       AND ( RELEASE_DATE <= Getutcdate() ) 
ORDER  BY IMPORTANT DESC, 
          DATE DESC, 
          LASTCHANGED DESC
```

This is an example of my data

```
  id       date     lastchanged important
187346  1366070400  1345212540  1
187306  1365984000  1345290300  1
187330  1365984000  1342457880  1
187344  1363392000  1342461540  1
187343  1363392000  1342461300  1
187342  1363392000  1342459980  1
187339  1363392000  1342459800  1
187337  1363392000  1342458960  1
187335  1363392000  1342458720  1
187334  1363392000  1342458600  1
187332  1363392000  1342458060  1
187331  1363392000  1342457940  1
187327  1363392000  1342457340  1
187328  1363392000  1342457340  1
187326  1363392000  1342456860  1
187323  1363392000  1342456020  1
187322  1363392000  1342455480  1
187321  1363392000  1342454700  1
187316  1363392000  1342454580  1
187320  1363392000  1342454520  1
```

Comment: id is uniques in table or it can be repeated?

Comment: So can't you just do WHERE id > $lastId? I'm confused.

Comment: I added the sample data to clear this up. If you notice the first 3 rows 187346, 187306, 187330. The IDs are not sorted

Comment: If your table does not contain an ID, where do you get it from? If your data does not have an ID you should remove it from the table.

Comment: Ah okay, so what do you need them selected from? Date? So everything from whichever date the last ID has? Oh wait, lastchanged would be what you're looking for right?

Comment: The table has an ID, but the query I need to use doesn't sort by ID. So it's just another value here

Comment: The lastedit doesn't mean the row is important. I still need the other ordering factors there and my question is about locating results after a specific ID

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
;WITH CTE( ROW,ID, 
                [date], 
                [lastchanged], 
                IMPORTANT ) AS
(
SELECT rOW_NUMBER() OVER(oRDER BY IMPORTANT DESC, 
          DATE DESC, 
          LASTCHANGED DESC ) AS rOW,ID, 
                Datediff(SECOND, CONVERT(DATETIME, '1970-01-01', 102), 
                RELEASE_DATE) AS date, 
                Datediff(SECOND, CONVERT(DATETIME, '1970-01-01', 102), EDIT_DATE 
                )    AS lastchanged, 
                IMPORTANT 
FROM   ARTICLES AS news WITH (NOLOCK) 
WHERE  ( STATUS = 1 ) 
       AND ( RELEASE_DATE <= Getutcdate() ) 
                ) 

SELECT TOP 20 ID, 
                [date], 
                [lastchanged], 
                IMPORTANT FROM CTE WHERE rOW>cOALESCE((sELECT rOW FROM CTE WHERE iD=1871),0);
```

Here is Example of this.In the example i select only top 5 so enter any id and you will that see it will fetch next five records.

[**Sql Fiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/3a4c0/22) -Enter wrong id for first like i here i entred -1 than you will get first five records.

[**Sql Fiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/3a4c0/23) -Enter  id=187339 since it last id for first page

[**Sql Fiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/3a4c0/24) -Enter  id=187331  since it last id for second page and so on

Answer (score 2):

If what you want to do is show 20 posts at a time in some application and to be able to fetch then next 20 posts until the end of the results maybe using the [OFFSET FETCH clause](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg699618.aspx) might work.

The initial query would be:

```
SELECT        
    id, DATEDIFF(SECOND, CONVERT(DATETIME, '1970-01-01', 102), release_date) AS date,  DATEDIFF(SECOND, CONVERT(DATETIME, '1970-01-01', 102), edit_date) AS lastchanged, important
FROM articles AS news WITH (NOLOCK)
WHERE (status = 1) AND (release_date <= GETUTCDATE())
ORDER BY important DESC, date DESC, lastchanged DESC
OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 20 ROWS ONLY;
```

and subsequent queries would increase the `offset`value:

```
SELECT        
    id, DATEDIFF(SECOND, CONVERT(DATETIME, '1970-01-01', 102), release_date) AS date,  DATEDIFF(SECOND, CONVERT(DATETIME, '1970-01-01', 102), edit_date) AS lastchanged, important
FROM articles AS news WITH (NOLOCK)
WHERE (status = 1) AND (release_date <= GETUTCDATE())
ORDER BY important DESC, date DESC, lastchanged DESC
OFFSET 20 ROWS FETCH NEXT 20 ROWS ONLY;
```

Comment: The problem is I don't have a page index to use as an offset, all I have is the last ID in the previous query

Comment: @ComputerJy Yeah, for this to work you would have to store the page-offset in a variable in the calling application.

Comment: @ComputerJy you can try the answer give below.